# Is there any way to update the appearance of one RecyclerView element without a full reload?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I'm making an app that has a main RecyclerView "feed" comprised of post elements.

You can click on a post which takes you to a detailed view.

I opted to put the detailed view in a "transparent" activity so that when the detailed view is clicked on, the current activity is paused and the new one starts. This means that the feed activity does not lose its state and the recyclerview maintains its position so that when the user clicks back the activity/fragment does not need to reload.

On both the feed's posts and the detailed view, I have thumb buttons that can be clicked. When the user enters the detailed view, I pass in the thumb button's state and it's initialized in onCreate(). When the user exits the detailed view, I need to update the state of the thumb button in the main feed (to keep them in sync) without refreshing the entire recyclerview. **This requires me refreshing the dataset (and subsequently updating the appearance) in one item of the recyclerview without refreshing/reloading the entire recyclerview. Is this possible?**

I tried doing this by updating the data set used by my adapter and calling notifyItemChanged(position) but this did not work. I was told this method calls onBindViewHolder (which would then call my bind method and update the view).

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Here, I'm updating my mRecipes data set after returning from the detailed view

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        int adaptpos = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("adaptpos"));
        String likes = data.getStringExtra("likes");
        String favorites = data.getStringExtra("favorites");
        mRecipes[adaptpos].setLikes(likes);
        mRecipes[adaptpos].setFavorites(favorites);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(adaptpos);

    }
}
```

Any help going about this would be greatly appreciated. If all else fails, I may have to just reload the entire fragment to reflect the change in state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) to handle this scenario , its an easy way to handle updates to recycler view items and was recently added to the support library.

This [medium](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/diffutil-is-a-must-797502bc1149#.98rippr4e) post explains the implementation

Comment: Appreciate the answer, I'm checking it out now.

Comment: No, DiffUtil update the whole list, you can use it instead of notifyDataSetChanged() and it will be great, but for one item it is recommended to use notifyItemChanged(), whit DiffUtil it has payload and not recommended for one item

Comment: yeah if its just one element you could use one of the following methods depending on if its removed/changed/added  


- notifyItemChanged(int)  
- notifyItemInserted(int)  
- notifyItemRemoved(int)  
- notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)
- notifyItemRangeInserted(int, int)
- notifyItemRangeRemoved(int, int)